# How do I accurately measure the B value of an NTC thermistor?

Tags: resistance, measurement, temperature, thermistor

I'm trying to find a part number for an NTC thermistor being used to monitor the temperature of a rechargeable battery. The thermistor I have has no color markings or numbers to indicate any information. I have measured the resistance at multiple temperatures, but I am worried my calculations are not very accurate, as I just used an ice cube and the hot surface of a food warmer. I need to ensure that the resistance - temperature curve matches the one of the thermistor I have, so that the battery charges when it should. Is there any sort of tool made to reliably produce different temperatures for measurement, or a better way I could go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wrap the thermistor in a waterproof heatproof enclosure (say, copper pipe soldered shut on one end) then an easy way to produce known temperatures is to use water's phase changes.

- Boiling water is at 100 °C (with correction for your local air pressure based on altitude).
- A mixture of water and ice (neither all melted nor all solid) is at 0 °C (after the water, if added separately, has cooled down; better but slower to let the ice melt to make the water).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am having the same issue nearly. Finding beta, the B value of unknown thermistor. And the formulae is

```
BETA = LN(Rt1/Rt2) /(1/T1-1/T2)
Rt1=Resistance at T1
Rt2=Resistance at T2
T1= Temperature 1 in K
T2= Temperature 2 in K
K= Kelvin = C +273.15
```

So using a published table of resistance such as [this](https://www.bapihvac.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Thermistor_10K-2.pdf), we find that at 25C Rt1 is 10000 Ohm. and at 35C Rt2 is 6530 Ohm.

Plugging in the values to google calculator , result is 3915.50844754.

Hope it helps.